# CSS's background-image in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, maven

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I'm trying to make a website using springboot but I can't add a background image to it. this is how I'm doing it:

[image]

```
body {
   background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
}
```

I've also tried using src/main/java/images/background.jpg, still doesnt work.

(HTML files are in src/main/resources/templates folder and CSS files in src/main/resources/static folder)

Did i import the image correctly? Thank you for help

This is my HTML code (it's pretty bad, I can't really use it):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Catering Ristorazione C.S.L</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1> <strong><em>Catering Ristorazione C.S.L</em></strong></h1>
        <div> <hr> 
        <a th:href="@{/elencochefs}" >Elenco degli chef</a>
        </div>
        <div> 
        <a th:href="@{/elencobuffets}" >Elenco dei buffet</a> 
        </div>
         </hr> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does moving your image `background.jpg` to `src/main/resources/static/images/` work?

Comment: should i try it using the url src/main/resources/static/images/background.jpg? @howlger

Comment: Could it be I didnt import it as I should? I took a picture from google, saved it and imported by dragging it into eclipse....or maybe my html code is wrong? Should I create a new body part just for it?

Answer (score 0):

Move your folder images to /src/main/resources/static

Also, you should modify your stylesheet to start the background-url with /.

```
body {
   background-image: url(/images/background.jpg);
}
```